# Bayesian Belief Network - directions of arcs between nodes

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

I generated a BBN below based on environmental variables and a response of some organism.

[image: BBN]

My aim here is to see how environmental variables (A-H in a graph above) interact with each other and influence organisms (phenotypic response). The sensitivity of "organism" is as follows:

Sensitivity of 'organism' to a finding at another node:

```
Node                Variance    Percent   Variance of 
----                Reduction             Beliefs     
Target              0.00393     100       0.2004898   
A                   0.003929    100       0.2004673   
B                   0.001801    45.8      0.0919060   
C                   0.001537    39.1      0.0783964   
D                   0.001203    30.6      0.0613732   
E                   0.001027    26.1      0.0523963   
F                   0.0009696   24.7      0.0494689   
G                   0.0009023   23        0.0460363   
H                   0.0007741   19.7      0.0394967
```

All good except a direction of arc between A and B. The direction is actually counter-intuitive. But when I reverse the direction, the sensitivity drops.

Is it feasible to say B potentially influence "organism" through interaction with A? Based on this model, is it ok to say B influences A? But how can I explain the direction of arc between A and B?

My guess is that a probability of A can be best predicted by a combination of E, F and G, but not with B, and information on A helps predict a probability of B. So the direction between A and B is not necessarily mean that A affects B (i.e. B would affect A and also indirectly affect organism).